# Alerting ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to read the response of ajax request in codeigniter, but couldn't do so uptill now, I have tried to many ways, but failed (stringify, console.log)

controller to which ajax request is sent

```
function func()
{
    echo json_encode("a");
}
```

ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/file/func",
    data: {},
    success: function(result){
        //how to alert "a" here??????
    },
});
```

help please

Comment: make sure action is called via ajax

Comment: the function is `json_encode`, not `json_encoded`

Comment: `console.log(result)` does work here.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question, is there any other way else then console.log ?

Comment: use your browser web tools. In Chrome goto Network -> XHR

Answer (score 0):

It is `json_encode` instead of `json_encoded` and

change: `//how to alert "a" here?????`
to: `alert(result);`

Comment: What do you mean in js file it doesn't, this is a js function so it is in a js file right? And what error do you get then?

Comment: it says, undefined characters, thats why json_encoding is used, js file does not allow php variables to alert